# What is Horn clause in prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic

I don't understand what the Horn clause is in prolog. 
• A Horn clause is a clause with exactly one positive literal.

```
     root(X) :- \+ left(X,Y), \+ right(X,Y).
```

So for this one it is not a horn clause cause it has multiple clauses? Or is there having any way to express it as a horn clause?

Comment: I urge you to visit this [link](http://www.learnprolognow.org/slides/official/Horn.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `\+` stands for negation as failure(*), the clause you give as an example does not have a pure logical meaning but depends on the evaluation strategy of Prolog. In classical logic, a horn clause is a clause which has at most one positive literal. Using logical notation, it can be written as `¬ A1 ∨ ... ∨ ¬ An ∨ B` which is equivalent to `A1 ∧ ... ∧ An → B`. In human words, this means: suppose A1 to An can be proved, then we can prove B. In Prolog, we write this backwards as `b :- a1, ..., an.` There's a special form called a fact, when we know that something is true without conditions. Logically, you can write this as `true → A`, in Prolog this just becomes `a.`.

(*) A formula is false because it can't be proven true. Another closely related keyword you can google for is closed world assumption.

Comment: Here is a donation: ¬, ∨, ∧, →